# Django restricting users from updating/deleting other users posts

Tags: python, html, django, backend, blogs

views.py

```
 @login_required(login_url='/login')
    def updatepost(request,pk):
        post = Post.objects.get(id=pk)
        form = PostForm(instance=post)
    
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return redirect ('mainpage')
    context = {'form':form}
    return render( request, 'postform.html', context )
```

postform.html

```
{% include 'main.html'%}

{% block content %}


{%if user.is_authenticated%}
    {% if user.id == post.user.id%} 
            <div>
                
                <form method="POST" action ="">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{form.as_p}}
                    <input type="Submit" value ="Submit"/>
                </form>
            </div>
    
            {%endif%}
{%endif%}

{% endblock content %}
```

I am trying to restrict user who is logged in - from updating , deleting other users posts.
However when I Try to use {% if user.id == post.user.id%}  , the page becomes blank even for the user who is editing his own post. The same goes for deleting.
It works on mainpages - where posts are displayed (it hides edit and delete buttons).
What is the reason that the post is not showing inside the template ?

I don't understand that even {{post.user}} in postform.html does not appear , neither on deleteform etc. - why this data of objects of a post is not being sent to postform.html ?

Answer (score 1):

You should change the context to access the post instance from your template.

```
context = {'form': form, 'post': post}
```

You can only access the context values from the templates. So pass the ones you want to use while you are returning a response.